# Custom Wordpress Taxonomy (Actors), show today's birthdays on homepage with query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a movie website, with movies as posts, and actors as a custom taxonomy.  For my custom taxonomy, I added this in my functions.php file:

```
    $labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Actors', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Actor', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Actors', 'textdomain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Actors', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Actors', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'                => null,
    'parent_item_colon'          => null,
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Actor', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Actor', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Actor', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Actor Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate actors with commas', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove actors', 'textdomain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used actors', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'No actors found.', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Actors', 'textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'actor' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'actor', 'post', $args );
```

I have added a field to the actor taxonomy with their date of birth (in yyyy-mm-dd format) in my functions.php file:

```
function crq_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {    
// this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page 
?>  
<div class="form-field">            
    <label for="term_meta[starbday]"><?php _e( 'Birthdate', 'responsivo' ); ?></label>          
    <input type="text" name="term_meta[starbday]" id="term_meta[starbday]" value="">        
    <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter Birthdate (in <em>yyyy-mm-dd</em> format)','responsivo' ); ?></p>   
</div>
<?php }
 add_action( 'actor_add_form_fields', 'crq_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Edit term page
function crq_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
// put the term ID into a variable      
$t_id = $term->term_id;     
// retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array        

$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );    
?>
<tr class="form-field">     
<th scope="row" valign="top">
<label for="term_meta[starbday]"><?php _e( 'Birthdate', 'responsivo' );     
?>      
</label>    
</th>               
<td>                
<input type="text" name="term_meta[starbday]" id="term_meta[starbday]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['starbday'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['starbday'] ) : ''; ?>">     
<p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter Birthdate (in <em>yyyy-mm-dd</em> format)','responsivo' ); ?></p>       
</td>   </tr>
add_action( 'actor_edit_form_fields', 'crq_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );
// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {        
if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {               
$t_id = $term_id;               
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );        
$cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );              
foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {                     
if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {    
$term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];           
}               
} 
// Save the option array.               
update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );  
}}  
add_action( 'edited_actor', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_actor', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

I am able to show this field on the actor's taxonomy page with the following code in the taxonomy template:

```
<?php 
$birthd = $term_meta['starbday'];
echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($birthd)); 
?>
```

Now, I am trying to run a query to show today's birthdays on the homepage.
This is what I have come up with so far.

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $todaymd = date('m-d');
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'orderby' => 'name'
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'starbday',
                'value' => '_____'.$todaymd, 
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'actor', $args );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This isn't working at all, and nothing is displayed.  While this would be the case if there were no birthdays on today's date, even if I change `$todaymd` to `'03-15'` (which I know is the birth month and day of several actors), it still displays nothing. Any suggestions?

I saw something similar asked here...https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82323/how-can-i-get-the-actor-birthday-by-date, but that wasn't answered, as the solution didn't work.

Comment: I have seen something on https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/23/4-4-taxonomy-roundup/ about a new taxonomy update with WordPress 4.4, but am not sure how this applies/doesn't apply to this.

Comment: It doesn't work because you used `update_option()` to save the term's meta data. Secondly, although it's possible, it's pretty complicated to make the `get_terms()` query work; I mean, for searching "actors" with the specified birth month and day. So in short, migrate your functions to use `update_term_meta()` (and `get_term_meta()`). Then you can do the `meta_query` via, for example, `get_terms()`. I can show sample code, if you still need it.

Comment: If you could provide some sample code, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Sally J, I figured it out, thanks to https://www.wphub.com/blog/posts/adding-metadata-taxonomy-terms/ (**whoops! wrong link!** see addition below) for the functions.php section and updating the homepage with this:

```
<ul>
     <?php 
     $todaymd = date('m-d');
     $args = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'actor',
         'orderby' => 'name',
         'order' => 'ASC',
     );
     $terms = get_terms( $args );
     foreach( $terms as $term ) { 
         $starbday = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'starbday', true);
         if((substr($starbday,5,5)) == $todaymd) { ?>
               <li><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
         <?php } else { }} ?>
</ul>
```

It does work now, but it doesn't seem to be the most efficient way (since I am pulling all the actors then filtering them, rather than filtering while getting them), but it works.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE** Since I put in the wrong link above, this is what is in my functions.php now:

```
// Add term page for Actor, Director and Book Author Taxonomies
add_action('actor_add_form_fields', 'crq_metabox_add', 10, 1); 
add_action('actor_edit_form_fields', 'crq_metabox_edit', 10, 1);

function crq_metabox_add($tag) {
?>
    <div class="form-field">            
        <label for="crq_starbday"><?php _e( 'Birthdate', 'responsivo' ); ?></label>         
        <input type="text" name="crq_starbday" id="crq_starbday" value="">      
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter Birthdate (in <em>yyyy-mm-dd</em> format)','responsivo' ); ?></p>   
    </div>
<?php }

// Edit term page for Actor, Director and Book Author Taxonomies

function crq_metabox_edit($tag) {
?>

<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top">
        <label for="crq_starbday"><?php _e( 'Birthdate', 'responsivo' ); ?></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="crq_starbday" id="crq_starbday" value="<?php echo get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'crq_starbday', true); ?>" />
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter Birthdate (in <em>yyyy-mm-dd</em> format)','responsivo' ); ?></p>       
    </td>   
</tr>
<?php 
}

// Save extra fields for Actor, Director and Book Author Taxonomies

add_action( 'created_actor', 'save_taxonomy_metadata', 10, 1 );  
add_action( 'edited_actor', 'save_taxonomy_metadata', 10, 1 );

function save_taxonomy_metadata($term_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['crq_starbday'])) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'crq_starbday', $_POST['crq_starbday']); 
    }
}
```

...which uses the new(er) `update_term_meta()`.  I tried using `meta_query()` on the homepage, but it didn't display any results (probably because `$todaymd` and `starbday` are so different (`starbday` is yyyy-mm-dd, while `$todaymd` is just mm-dd).  And the `'_____'.$todaymd` value doesn't work, either.

Comment: If you've migrated to using `update_term_meta()` to save the meta data, then you should have no problems of using the `meta_query` with the `get_terms()` function. I.e. `'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'starbday', value => $todaymd, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) );`. But I'm referring to the native `update_term_meta()` function in WordPress verson 4.4.0 and above. =)

Comment: Actually, the `meta_query` does work now with `LIKE`.  I forgot I had updated my field to `crq_starbday`.  Thank you!